# How to delete all specific xml element using Element Tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I need to delete the particular XML elements in all occurrences in a file.

But I tried many times, but I am unable to delete using the Element Tree python.

In below XML content, I need to delete all `<decade>` elements.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
<page>
    <genre>
        <decade>
            <movie>
                <rating>PG</rating>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade>
            <movie>
               <rating>PG-13</rating>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <name>DVD-2001</name>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <decade>
            <movie>
                <rating>R</rating>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <name>DVD-1989</name>
    </genre>
</page>
```

Could anyone help me to delete the element of all occurrences in the above text.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the code below also removes any child nodes of the `decade` elements.

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO

data = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page>
    <genre>
        <decade>
            <movie>
                <rating>PG</rating>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <decade>
            <movie>
               <rating>PG-13</rating>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <name>DVD-2001</name>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <decade>
            <movie>
                <rating>R</rating>
            </movie>
        </decade>
        <name>DVD-1989</name>
    </genre>
</page>
'''

f = StringIO(data)
tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for g in tree.iter('genre'):
    for d in g.findall('decade'):
        g.remove(d)

f = BytesIO()
tree.write(f, encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)

print(f.getvalue().decode('UTF-8'))
```

Outputs

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<page>
    <genre>
        <name>DVD-2001</name>
    </genre>
    <genre>
        <name>DVD-1989</name>
    </genre>
</page>
```